# Single Node Module Mean Stack

Tags: mean-stack, node-modules

Can I use only 1 node modules in my project instead having multiple node modules?
1 for mongodb, expressjs and 1 for angular?
How to link node modules in 1 folder?

Comment: Who told you to use multiple node modules. You should have to use one node modules which contain the information for each.

Comment: because when i build MEAN stack 2 node_modules folder created 1 for mongo express and 1 for angular

Comment: No, You are wrong. There should be only one  node_modules folder.

Comment: seems like i wrong step when create mean stack, thx for info